# Learning python in a use-case - dictionaries as a global?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am in the process of learning python and would like to understand the correct pythonic approach to my code.

I am writing a utility that

1. Reads a list of file names and search terms
2. Opens each file, searches for the term and extracts some data from the matched line
3. Constructs a dictionary to hold a label term and a value
4. Output this dictionary to a CSV file

I have the code working - I have some tidying up to do and some streamlining - but would like to understand best practice approach.

So, the flow is as follows:

```
create global dictionary
report_outer_loop()
print_dict()

report_outer_loop
  open the list of reports
  for each item in list (the item contains report name, search term, etc)
    call report_inner_loop (item)

report_inner_loop (item)
  get reportname from item
  get search term from item  
  open report
  for each line in report
    find search_term
    update dictionary with extracted data

print_dict()
  for each item in dictionary
  write key, value to file
```

So, you can see I have a global dictionary that is accessed by the inner-loop, and the print_dict.
My question is: is this the correct, pythonic approach?
Or should I not create it as a global, but instead pass it to the outer_loop, and then the inner, and then the print functions?
Or there a better way?

Comment: How about wrapping those methods into a class and making that dict an attribute of the class instance?

Comment: @tobias_k That, or you might simply subclass `dict` itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with creating a local dictionary in `report_outer_loop`, pass it to `report_inner_loop` and return it as a result of running `report_outer_loop`.

Comment: Thanks Tomo - I've ticked this one as the best answer, because as yet, I don't yet know how to do classes! No doubt, as I learn more python, I'll be retuning this code!

Comment: @AstroDaz Both methods are fine (and _much_ better than global variables). Though personally I prefer not manipulating function parameters (other than `self`) if possible

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `dict`, adding your `report_outer_loop` as `append_reports` function. Then you can simply use `self.append(extracted_data)`.